# how to replace multiple codes

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace two strings from a code

```
command = input('command:')
command = command.replace("to my morning task", "")
print(command)
```

I want to remove "add" and "to my morning task" from the input(command)
though nothing is being removed and the same command is coming as output.

```
----RUN----
command:add programming to my morning routine
add programming to my morning routine
```

Comment: Please provide input that you entered.

Comment: It should be `to my morning routine` instead of `to my morning task` and then `command.replace("to my morning routine", "").replace("add","")` should work

Comment: Where is "to my morning task" in your input command?

Comment: the input and reasult is below -------RUN---------.

Comment: command.replace("to my morning routine", "").replace("add","")                                              it didn't work, the output is same.Do you have any more ideas?

Comment: You need to assign it to a variable like `command = command.replace("to my morning routine", "").replace("add","")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the format of replace function in python :

```
string.replace(old, new, count)
```

and her some example about replace function :

```
string = "geeks for geeks geeks geeks geeks"
```

## Prints the string by replacing geeks by Geeks

print(string.replace("geeks", "Geeks"))

## Prints the string by replacing only 3 occurence of Geeks

print(string.replace("geeks", "GeeksforGeeks", 3))

and when we come to your problem you have one parameter missing which is 'new an old values' please try `command = command.replace("add", "")`

Comment: -Rajdip Shah mark the answer so the other will use it immediately  
you welcome

Comment: Sorry I forgot to do that. Done